# RStudio Server on linux: how to create a shiny app that immediately returns user input text if button OK pressed, or FALSE if button CANCEL pressed

Tags: r, linux, shiny, dialog

I want my function to implement a dialog with an editable text box using a shiny app.

I.e. calling the function should open a shiny app displaying some text for the user to edit, then press the 'Ok' button to close the app and return the edited text or the 'Cancel' button to close the app and return an empty character vector.

My code runs fine on Windows (Rstudio desktop).
However on Linux (Rstudio Server Pro) the shiny page is displayed but the interface seems to be greyed, the text can be edited but the buttons are not responsive.  Why?

--**EDIT**--

The unresponsiveness problem occurs with Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge, not Chrome.  Although the page in Chrome is greyed too, and opening Chrome's 'Inspect' tool shows 2 errors:

```
(1) shinyapp.js:83 WebSocket connection to 'wss://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/websocket/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
(2) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'readyState' of null
    at ShinyApp.$sendMsg (shiny.min.js:3)
    at ShinyApp.sendInput (shiny.min.js:3)
    at InputBatchSender.$sendNow (shiny.min.js:3)
```

[where XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX stands for my Rstudio Server's URL]

```
library(shiny)


getMyText <- function(default = "This is my input\n- Anonymous") {
  require(stringr)
  ui <- fluidPage(
    textAreaInput("myTextBox", "Edit text", paste(default, collapse="\n"),
                  width = "600px", height = "400px"),
    actionButton("okBtn", "Ok"),
    actionButton("cancelBtn", "Cancel")
  )
  server <- function(input, output) {
    observe({
      if(input$cancelBtn > 0){
        stopApp(character(0))
      }
    });
    observe({
      if(input$okBtn > 0){
        stopApp(unlist(str_split(input$myTextBox, "\n")))
      } 
    });
  }
  return(runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server)))
}
args <- getMyText()
```

sessionInfo:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.4 (Maipo)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] stringr_1.3.1 shiny_1.4.0.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4      digest_0.6.18   later_1.0.0     mime_0.6        R6_2.4.1        xtable_1.8-3    magrittr_1.5    rlang_0.4.5    
 [9] stringi_1.1.7   promises_1.1.0  tools_3.5.0     httpuv_1.5.2    yaml_2.2.0      fastmap_1.0.1   compiler_3.5.0  htmltools_0.4.0
>
```

Comment: Interesting; your code seems to work fine on my Linux box (Ubuntu 20.04, R 4.0.0)

Comment: of course I don't have the latest R version - but then what?

Comment: Yeah, my point is, I'm not sure; as I didn't see any issue on my setup, and (at least to my eye) there's nothing obvious going on with your code itself, it's kind of hard for me to debug. You may have a tough one to crack here I guess is what I'm saying. Though hopefully maybe someone with more experience with RStudio Server could be more knowledgeable on whatever your specific issue is.

Comment: thanks anyway for looking into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this problem was due to a server (mis)configuration.
Interestingly, I found out that setting option `shiny.host` to the IP address of the server (instead of the default 127.0.0.1) enabled interaction with the shiny app, e.g.:

```
options(shiny.host = '10.1.2.3')
```

The following code could be used to set this option dynamically on a Linux host, useful in case load balancing gets the user connected to one of several Rstudio servers:

```
if (Sys.info()["sysname"] == 'Linux') {
  hostIP <- system("hostname -I | awk '{print $1}'", intern = TRUE)
  options(shiny.host = hostIP)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The greyed out screen to me sounds like your `observe` block is firing before all inputs are set up. This can be remedied in two ways:

```r
observe({
  req(input$cancelBtn)
  if (input$cancelBtn > 0) {
    stopApp(character(0))
  }
})
observeEvent(input$cancelBtn, {
  if (input$cancelBtn > 0) {
    stopApp(character(0))
  }
}, ignoreNULL = TRUE)     # which is the default, including it for clarity
```

FYI: win10, R-3.5.3, shiny-1.4.0

Comment: As I have 2 buttons and can click on either one, is req(input$cancelBtn) appropriate? should I add req(input$okBtn) as well ?

Comment: I think adding both is defensive. As to whether it is necessary ... I'm not proficient enough with `shiny` internals to know if one can guarantee the `observe` blocks will *never* fire prematurely ... but I know I have needed `req` in other similar situations (e.g., `selectInput` even with a default `selected=`), so I thought I'd suggest this. Either `req` or `observeEvent` should guard against it in this case. (Again, I don't know that this fixes your problem, but it should suffice if the greyed screen is due to early firing when the button is not yet defined, ergo `input$cancelBtn` is null.)

Comment: Sorry, thought it was worth a try.

Comment: I also noticed after opening the app in browser (internet explorer) and 'Inspect Element' that clicking on either button results in Console messages: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'readyState' of undefined or null reference. File: shiny.min.js, Line: 3, Column: 26688